# How to implement a board(with fixed dimensions) in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to implement a board game, using Prolog. The game consists of a board(10x5), two characters(a cop and a thief) and some objects scattered over the board. The objective is to find wheter there is a path from the cop to the thief, provided that the thief cannot move. I tried to define the cop's movement as follows:

```
/*Defining the movement along the x-axis*/
 cop(0).  /*Initial position.*/
 cop(W) :- cop(X), W is X+1, W < 10.
```

In doing so, I encountered two major problems: the solution above enters an infinite loop, when presented with the query "?- cop(X).", and prints the following

[image]

and when I try to make the cop move left, with : `cop(W) :- cop(X), W is X+1, W > 0.`, i get the same error message. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see how the details of your question relate to the title. Your question seems to be about why `cop` runs out of stack, and there's nothing in the predicate that suggests any kind of multi-dimensional "board". Your title is asking how to implement the board, which your question details don't seem to discuss.

Answer (score 2):

The essential problem here is that you define a *left-recursive* function:

```
cop(W) :-
    cop(X),
    ...
```

this means that Prolog can keep calling `cop/1`, since if you call `cop(W)`, you call `cop(X)`, and that `cop(X)`, will again result in a call to `cop(Y)`, etc. You only set bounds at the end, and thus there is no "guard" that protects against the recursion. Even if the "filtering" at the end lets all the suggested solutions fail, then nothing will prevent Prolog from retrying this, but with one recursive call extra. So after a while the filtering will discard all proposed solutions, but Prolog will keep searching for a valid solution.

A trick is thus here to limit the recursion, we can for example use the `clpfd` library to "limit" the bound of the `W` variable, and eventually obtain an empty domain, like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

cop(0).
cop(W) :- W #> 0, W #=< 10, W #= X+1, cop(X).
```

that being said, I am not confident that the above way to handle this puzzle. It looks like you will need to use *linear temporal logic (LTL)*, or *branching temporal logic (BTL)* here.

Comment: Oh thanks, it works! Do you happen to know how I can make the character walk left or right? I tried to add the line  "cop(W) :- W #> 0, W #=< 10, W #= X-1, cop(X)." ,but it didn't work.

Comment: @RodrigoS: because then you each time "decrement" `X`, so it will fail `W`, since if `cop(0)` is satisfied, then `X = 0` hence `W #= X-1`, so `W=-1`, but then this fails with the `W #> 0` constraint.

Comment: But even if I change the initial position to `cop(3).`, it enters an infinite loop, when presented with the query `?-cop(2).`. The intended behavior would be the cop going left from the position 3 and reaching the position 2.

Comment: @RodrigoS: if I replace `cop(0).` with `cop(3)`, and `W #= X+1`, with `W #= X-1`, then I get `X = 3`, `X = 2`, `X = 1`..

Comment: Yes. But if you query `?-cop(5).` in this second case, does it answer true? Because the character should be able to reach any position (wheter it is right or left) within the board's limit. So if I just replace `W #= X+1` with `W #= X-1`, the cop would only be able to go left (giving the answer false to `?-cop(5).`). Right?

Comment: It can not reach `true`, since here you let it range from `3` to `0`. But as said in the end of the answer, the approach you take does not look really promising to me as in defining such predicates looks quite "un-Prolog".

Comment: I'll try to approach it another way. Thank you very much!